# Writing an if statement in axios setting URL

Tags: node.js

I want to write an if statement in `axios` setting URL config to check if the method is post do not send the params but I get syntax error.

Something like code below

```
    if (method = 'GET') {
        params: req.params,
    },
```

Code without if statement that works fine:

```
    axios({
      url: API_URL + req.url,
      method: req.method,
      params: req.params,
      data: req.body,
      if (body) {

      }
    })
```

Comment: When one uses `someMethod({ .... })` it means one is passing an object as a parameter to a method named `someMethod`. If one needs to add an `optional` key-value pair into the parameter, this may be useful: `someMethod({ key1: "val1", key2: "val2", ...( someCondition ? {optionalKey1: "optionalVal1"} : {}) });`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `params` needs to be passed optional [from question: *check if the method is post do not send the params*] in the below code-sample:

```
axios({
  url: API_URL + req.url,
  method: req.method,
  params: req.params, // make this optional based on method != POST
  data: req.body,
})
```

Please try something like this:

```
axios({
  url: API_URL + req.url,
  method: req.method,
  data: req.body,
  ...(
    (req.method !== 'POST')
    ? { params: req.params }
    : {}
  )
});
```